# Scroll overflow: hidden content of fixed div with browser scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to scroll the content of a fixed div with the browser scrollbar.

Can that be done with pure CSS? If not how would you approach a solution with JQuery?

**I don't want the scrollbar within the div.**

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zy8qqmxa/

```
<div class="fixed-layer">
  <div class="content-layer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu
    feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui 
    <br />
    <strong>Scroll past this point with the browser scrollbar.</strong>
    <br />
    blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

  </div>
</div>

.fixed-layer {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 20px; 
  left: 20px; 
  width: 400px; 
  height: 400px; 
  overflow: hidden
}

.content-layer {


}
```

This is not the result I want!
[image]

Comment: Take a look to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747581/jquery-vertical-scroll-with-mousewheel)

Comment: Thanks, the scrolling works, but it lacks the actual scrollbar (for the user to notice, that there is something to scroll). Still the best solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it

```css
.fixed-layer {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 20px; 
  left: 20px; 
  width: 400px; 
  height: 400px; 
  overflow: Scroll;
}

.content-layer {


}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-layer">
  <div class="content-layer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu
    feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui 
    <br />
    <strong>Scroll past this point with the browser scrollbar.</strong>
    <br />
    blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That ads the scrollbar within the div, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
  <body>
  <div class="borderwrap top">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="fixed-layer">
  <div class="content-layer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu
    feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui 
    <br />
    <strong>Scroll past this point with the browser scrollbar.</strong>
    <br />
    blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="borderwrap bottom">&nbsp;</div>
  </body>

  .borderwrap {
    width: 387px;      
  }
  .borderwrap.top {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
  }
  .borderwrap.bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid;
  }
  .fixed-layer {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 400px;
  }
  .content-layer {
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
```

Comment: The scrollbar is still within the page. I want to use the scrollbar of the browser, please read my question.